# Apache only serving index.php in root directory

Tags: php, apache2

I am having trouble serving php files in the browser. I am using the directory at `/var/www/html/capstone`. I have enabled `mod_rewrite` and set `DocumentRoute` to the named directory. `.htaccess` contains `Rewrite On` and  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

All files and directories are owned by me with `755` for directories and `644` for files. I get a 500 error when trying to access the file directly at `localhost/controllers/<filename>.php`

I have added `php_flag display_errors 1` to the `.htaccess` file, but no errors display when I try to navigate to `localhost/controllers/<filename>.php` in the browser. My error log is this

> [Fri Feb 09 11:51:11.319674 2024] [php:warn] [pid 15444] [client 127.0.0.1:60550] PHP Warning:  require(views/home.view.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/capstone/controllers/index.php on line 2
>
> [Fri Feb 09 11:51:11.319736 2024] [php:error] [pid 15444] [client 127.0.0.1:60550] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'views/home.view.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/capstone/controllers/index.php:2\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/capstone/controllers/index.php on line 2
>
> [Fri Feb 09 11:51:20.145142 2024] [php:error] [pid 15445] [client 127.0.0.1:60552] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function dd() in /var/www/html/capstone/controllers/signup.php:2\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/capstone/controllers/signup.php on line 2

Access.log is this

> 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2024:12:07:14 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3081 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
>
> 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2024:12:07:20 -0500] "GET /signup HTTP/1.1" 404 488 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
>
> 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2024:12:08:12 -0500] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"

So it seems like `/` is getting a 200 status code, but all other routes get a 404.

UPDATE: I confirmed that the router file is properly fetching files from the controllers directory.

Comment: _All files and directories are owned by me with 755_ Should they not be owned by the account that the webserver is runung under? Often `www`

Comment: That's what I thought too. But if I don't own the files I can't edit them in vscode. I feel like it's defintely a permission issue.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30879/what-user-should-apache-and-php-be-running-as-what-permissions-should-var-www

Comment: I tried allowing root to own the files, and www-data, but neither worked. This problem existed with the default permissions before I started messing with them.

Comment: I confirmed that my routing is working. So it's not a permission issue.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by spinning up a server with php -s localhost:8080 so obviously something wrong with my apache webserver, but I can't locate the problem

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put complete file address at "/var/www/html/capstone/controllers/index.php", enough with "localhost/captstone/controllers" with "index.php", or "localhost/captstone/controllers/<another_php_file.php>" for example.

Comment: As I mentioned in my update the routing file is working properly. All file paths are correct, because the php server is working.